# LINQ to SQL top and order by in subquery

Tags: linq, subquery, sql-order-by

I need next SQL query:

```
SELECT [t1].[monthp], [t1].[yearp], [t1].[coeftarif]
FROM [dbo].[sal_hightariff] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[sal_tarifstav] AS [t1] ON ((
    SELECT TOP (1) [t3].[code_no]
    FROM [dbo].[sal_tarifstav] AS [t3]
    WHERE ([t3].[codetnum] = @codetnum) AND ([t3].[yearp] = [t0].[yearp]) AND ([t3].[monthp] = [t0].[monthp])
    ORDER BY [t3].[datestart]
    )) = [t1].[code_no]
WHERE [t0].[yearp] * 12 + [t0].[monthp] >= @value1 AND [t0].[yearp] * 12 + [t0].[monthp] <= value2
```

So, I write this code:

```
var coeflist = from high in dbContext.sal_hightariff
               join stav in dbContext.sal_tarifstav on (from tarifstav in dbContext.sal_tarifstav
                                                        where tarifstav.codetnum == vacationcodetnum
                                                            && tarifstav.yearp == high.yearp
                                                            && tarifstav.monthp == high.monthp
                                                        orderby tarifstav.datestart
                                                        select tarifstav.code_no).FirstOrDefault() equals stav.code_no
               where high.yearp * 12 + high.monthp >= minday.Year * 12 + minday.Month
                    && high.yearp * 12 + high.monthp <= vacationdatestart.Year
                        * 12 + vacationdatestart.Month
               select new
               {
                   stav.monthp,
                   stav.yearp,
                   stav.coeftarif
               };
```

But my code generates:

```
SELECT [t1].[monthp], [t1].[yearp], [t1].[coeftarif]
FROM [dbo].[sal_hightariff] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[sal_tarifstav] AS [t1] ON ((
    SELECT TOP (1) [t3].[code_no]
    FROM (
        SELECT [t2].[code_no], [t2].[codetnum], [t2].[yearp], [t2].[monthp]
        FROM [dbo].[sal_tarifstav] AS [t2]
        ORDER BY [t2].[datestart]
        ) AS [t3]
    WHERE ([t3].[codetnum] = @p0) AND ([t3].[yearp] = [t0].[yearp]) AND ([t3].[monthp] = [t0].[monthp])
    )) = [t1].[code_no]
    WHERE ((((CONVERT(Int,[t0].[yearp])) * @p1) + (CONVERT(Int,[t0].[monthp]))) >= @p2)
        AND ((((CONVERT(Int,[t0].[yearp])) * @p3) + (CONVERT(Int,[t0].[monthp]))) <= @p4)
```

In which there is an error:

> Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 13 The ORDER BY clause is invalid in
>   views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table
>   expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

So, if I use methods FirstorDefault() or Take(1) in subquery, LINQ generates SELECT TOP (1) FROM SELECT ... But I need TOP (1) inside subquery to use ORDER BY statement.

Comment: What about `Take(int.MaxValue)` ?

Comment: @leppie I need just 1 row and TOP (1) statement should by by inside scope with ORDER BY statement

Comment: See my answer on **[SQL Server Query Error -ORDER BY clause is invalid in views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36697511/sql-server-query-error-order-by-clause-is-invalid-in-views/61702593#61702593)**.