# SQL Server Query Error -ORDER BY clause is invalid in views

Tags: sql-server, view

I am running the below code. When I run this code, I get error message:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR
>   XML is also specified.

I'm not sure why I am getting this error message. Help is much appreciated.

```
SELECT  a.DELINQ_BUCKET_GROUP, a.vv_count
FROM 
(   
    SELECT  DELINQ_BUCKET_GROUP, 
            CASE WHEN DELINQ_BUCKET_GROUP IS NULL THEN 
                    SUM(CASE WHEN DELINQ_BUCKET_GROUP IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                ELSE COUNT(DELINQ_BUCKET_GROUP) 
            END AS vv_count 
    FROM    DCSReporting.dbo.DIM_DELINQUENT_BUCKET
    GROUP BY DELINQ_BUCKET_GROUP
    ORDER BY vv_count DESC
) a
WHERE rownum<=100
```

Comment: The error message is very clear; you can't use `order by` in a sub-query. Also, there is no point to use it, a sub-query is just a set as any other. Why would you want to sort an intermediate set? You want to order your result set.

Comment: rownum is an oracle feature. Are you really sure you're working with SQL Server?

Comment: The next error you are likely to encounter (invalid column name rownum) is because you don't have a column named rownum in your derived table.

Comment: Unless you are trying to create a derived table on the top 100 records ordered by vv_count???
In that case you would need to add a `TOP (100)` operator between your `SELECT` and `DELINQ_BUCKET_GROUP`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order BY is not supported in view in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26888472/order-by-is-not-supported-in-view-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using `SQL Server 2012` or later version, use `Offset 0 Rows` after `Order By`:

```
SELECT Id,
       Name       
FROM Table

ORDER BY Id 
OFFSET 0 ROWS
```