# I'm getting the error "Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 14 The ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to run the following query and I'm getting this error:

> Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
>   The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Here is the query:

```
WITH cbt_users AS 
(
    SELECT
        mo, eid, rate, cat, quantity AS cbt_hours
    FROM
        crew.crew_rates
    WHERE
        rate_type = 'HOMSTUDY_HRS'
),
tot_hrs AS 
(
    SELECT
        mo, eid, rate, quantity AS tot_hrs
    FROM
        crew.crew_rates
    WHERE
        rate_type = 'TOT HRS'
),
GU_cbt_compare AS 
(
    SELECT
        cbt_users.mo, cbt_users.eid, cbt_users.rate, cbt_hours, tot_hrs,
        CASE WHEN cbt_users.cat = 'REG' THEN 72 ELSE 75 END AS min_GU
    FROM
        cbt_users 
    LEFT JOIN 
        tot_hrs ON cbt_users.mo = tot_hrs.mo AND cbt_users.eid = tot_hrs.eid
    ORDER BY 
        cbt_users.mo, cbt_users.eid
)
SELECT
    mo, eid, rate, cbt_hours, tot_hrs, min_GU
FROM
    GU_cbt_compare
ORDER BY 
    mo, eid
```

Comment: You have an order by clause in your GU_cbt_compare cte, remove it. The error message told you the problem.

Comment: Which part of the error message is not clear?  I don't know how else can we explain it to you.  CTE can't have order by.

Comment: Thanks Sean Lange. I removed the ORDER BY clause and gave the right results.

Comment: Thanks to Eric as well for quick response.

Comment: @Cunha See my answer on **[SQL Server Query Error -ORDER BY clause is invalid in views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36697511/sql-server-query-error-order-by-clause-is-invalid-in-views/61702593#61702593)**.