# Joining table and etc

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote the below query to join table `Pro_C_C` with `Pol_C_C` (I only picked up 6 fields from `Pol_C_C`).

```
Select *
From Pro_C_C x
Join
(Select 
[Policy Number],
LEFT([Primary Policyholder Forename],1) PInitial, [Primary Policyholder Surname] PrimPHSurname,[Primary Policyholder Dob] PrimPHDOB,
LEFT([Secondary Policyholder Forename],1) SInitial, [Secondary Policyholder Surname]SecPHSurname,[Secondary Policyholder Dob] SecPHDOB
From Pol_C_C) y
On x.[Policy Number] = y.[Policy Number]
Order By x.[Policy Number]
```

Then I wrote the below trying but I am getting the error

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

```
Select
[PN],[PT],[IPL1],[IPL2],[IPL3],[IPL4],[IPL5],[IPP],[IPO],[IPBA],[PID-UPRN],[PIS Date],[PIE Date],[PPF],[PPS],[PPD]
From(
Select * From Pro_C_C x
Join
(Select 
[PN],
LEFT([PPF],1) PPF, [PPS],[PPD],
LEFT([SPF],1) SPF, [SPS],[SPD]
From Pol_C_C) y
On x.[PN] = y.[PN]
Order By x.[PolPN]
)A
```

Anyone got any idea?

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  It seems really clear.  If you want the results in a particular order, then the `ORDER BY` needs to be associated with the *outer* `SELECT`.

Comment: I am just not sure how to fix it, because even if I take the Order By out ofthe formula it is still don't work...

Comment: what error do you get when you remove the order by?

Comment: See my answer on **[SQL Server Query Error -ORDER BY clause is invalid in views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36697511/sql-server-query-error-order-by-clause-is-invalid-in-views/61702593#61702593)**.